# Creating Stored Proc to Insert into a View

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, view

I have created some new tables that I need to insert to on a semi-regular basis. Due to normalization I decided to build a view on top of the base tables to make reports more logical for myself and EU's. I got the bright idea to try to use a stored procedure to push inserts into the base tables via a different view. I can run the insert statement in SSMS successfully, but when I try to create it into a stored procedure it will run because it appears to think my insert is a function.

Here is the error:

```
Msg 215, Level 16, State 1, Procedure jedi.p_ForcePush, Line 12
Parameters supplied for object 'jedi.v_midichlorians' which is not a function. If the parameters are intended as a table hint, a WITH keyword is required.
```

Here is my script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE jedi.p_ForcePush
    @Field varchar(25) = NULL,
    @Value varchar(250) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    insert  jedi.v_midichlorians (@field) values (@value)   
END
GO
```

I have poured out my petition to the googles but haven't found a good solution. I have tried lots of different combo's in my syntax but nothing doing.

Any help is much appreciated! (ps-SQL 2012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE jedi.p_ForcePush
    @Field varchar(25) = NULL,
    @Value varchar(250) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql =  N'INSERT INTO  jedi.v_midichlorians (' + QUOTENAME(@field) 
          + N') values (@value)'

  EXECUTE sp_executesql  @sql
                        , N'@Value varchar(250)'  
                        , @Value
END
GO
```

When you pass @field param as a parameter sql server treats it as a string not an object name, Using `QUOTENAME()` wraps the passed column name in `[]` square brackets telling sql server explicitly that it is an object(Table, column) name.

On a side note If your View has only one underlying table on then use view to insert values other wise use the table name.

If you do have more then one underlying table in your View's definition and you want to insert data using view then you will need to create `Instead of triggers`.

Best option is to do all insert, update delete operation directly to tables, avoid using views and then triggers for view based on more then one underlying tables.

Comment: worked Perfectly! Much appreciated...and I learned something new

Answer (score 0):

though you mentioned that insert stmts run fine in ssMS, can you confirm that the same insert stmt you ran in SSMS ? becaus ethere is an error in this stmt.

"insert  jedi.v_midichlorians (@field)"

syntex is inccoect and column name should dnot have "@" right?

also is this view based on a single table ?

Comment: The view is based on multiple tables. The tables are normalized and the view makes it easier to see all the pertinent information. It should also simplify the insert process since all my column names are in one place.

Comment: I am trying to get the stored procedure to provide input parameters for the field and value. The variables are varchar which i was thinking would be parsed correctly but maybe I need to include quotes to notate string?

Comment: as Ali has mentioned, in you case your view is based on multiple tables and Insert can not be done through view if it is based on multiple tables. views are good for Select as the complex join and all filter you can wrap inside it and your select query remain simple. Anyways in your case you should use directly table name with Dynamic SQL as Ali explained.